# Google's service directory listUsers isn't returning any users

Tags: php, laravel, google-api-php-client

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users) I should be able to search on the alias email address. The code above doesn't return any users. I know that this alias (myusername@mydomain.com) exists in my account because I can see it and set it up manually yet the api isn't finding it. I'm using the https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client library.

What am I doing wrong?
I'm trying both of these calls:

```
$google_service_directory = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$google_service_directory_users = $google_service_directory->users->listUsers([
            'domain' => 'mydomaim.com',
            'query' => 'email=myusername@mydomain.com'
        ]);
```

OR

```
$google_service_directory_users = $google_service_directory->users->listUsers([
            'domain' => 'mydomaim.com',
            'query' => 'myusername@mydomain.com'
        ]);
```

Here is the output when I print the google_service_directory_users variable:

```
Google_Service_Directory_Users {#631
  #collection_key: "users"
  #internal_gapi_mappings: array:1 [
    "triggerEvent" => "trigger_event"
  ]
  +etag: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  +kind: "admin#directory#users"
  +nextPageToken: null
  +triggerEvent: null
  #usersType: "Google_Service_Directory_User"
  #usersDataType: "array"
  #modelData: array:1 [
    "users" => []
  ]
  #processed: array:1 [
    "users" => true
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need iterate $google_service_directory_users...Here a example:

```
    <?php
        $pageToken  = null;
        $directorio = new Google_Service_Directory( $cliente );
    
        $optParams  = array(
            'domain' => 'mydomaim.com',
            'query' => 'email=myusername@mydomain.com'
        );
    
        do
        {
            if( $pageToken )
                $optParams['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
    
            $resultado  = $directorio -> users -> listUsers( $optParams );
            $pageToken  = $resultado -> getNextPageToken( );
    
            foreach( $resultado -> getUsers() as $usuario )
            {
                printf( "Email: %s Name: %s Created: %s, Last access: %s 
", $usuario -> getPrimaryEmail(), $usuario -> getName() -> getFullName(), $usuario -> getCreationTime(), $usuario -> getLastLoginTime( ) );
            }
    
        }while( $pageToken );
    ?>
```